# Excel - find multiple pieces of data in several different columns at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've currently got a spreadsheet on the go which lists contracts. I need to know if a contract is a renewal, new to product, or new to company. I'm currently struggling with the logic behind it and would appreciate any help!

As the reporting software doesn't ask about the various types of contract, I'm left with less information than I'd like.

As well as From and To dates, Each customer has a unique identifier, each product has a specified name, and each contract has a unique number as well as a current "status". for the contracts with several different versions, I've also added a "latest version" column

Sample:

```
CompanyNumber   Product     Contract Number     Version     Status   Latest version?   Valid From      Valid To
12345              A            9876A-BA           1        Active        Yes             1/1/14       31/12/15
```

What I need to do is generate additional "Yes/No" columns for `New Customer`, `New to product`, And `Renewal`.

This should then allow me to much more easily create monthly reports for those three columns, simply by filtering for them in PivotTables.

I've already generated several extra columns for other reasons as follows

```
Start date in this month? - End Date In This Month - Expires in next three months?  - More than one version? - Existing Client > 365 days - Latest version?
```

The logic I've got at the moment for Renewals is to firstly check if another entry with the same company number has an end date within the last year, and then to check if the latest version of the contract both starts this month and is the latest version, like so

```
If
   unique company number = no, find if any duplicate result ended in the last year
                              AND
   Contract Starts this month AND this entry is the latest version 
= True, "YES"
  False = "NO"
```

I'm stuck for how to do this though! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

EDIT.

After a days trying I got this far. I think it works but I'm not 100%

I started trying this as an if function, with nested and, countif (unique company number) >1, countif(product)>1, current, and latest version functions like this:
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B10)>1,COUNTIF(C:C,C10)>1,(S10="Yes"),AA10=1),1,0)

Answers are coming through as 1 or 0 so I can use the results in a Pivot table with ease.

If anyone thinks of a better answer let me know :) -

SECOND EDIT

That one wasn't working, so I've done some more research and found this formula, which isn't quite working.

I've decided to make a "helper" column so we can count the instance of every product per company number, but it's counting EVERY instance of the company number, not just the ones that cross reference the product.

```
=SUM(IF(C:C=C28,IF(B:B=B28,1,0),0))
```

Where `C:C` is the column I'm storing product numbers in and `B` is the unique company reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of times I will use concatenate to combine elements of data and then use a pivot table to count the number of times a combined data element occurs, or you can use count if. So for example, if you are trying to find out if a Company (Company Number) is new to a Product than you could create a helper column with the formula `=Concatenate(Company Number, Product)` which in your example would give you the value `12345A`. You could then use `countif` or a pivot table to see 1) if the company is new to that product line 2) the start date (Valid From) etc.

Comment: Thanks User1813558, I think this will help with what I'm doing. At the moment I'm looking at using your solution to create a helper column, which I can then cross reference with whether it's a unique or not. Unique result = Renewal, Non-Unique = new to product.

Comment: That's great. Let me know if you encounter any other problems.